# Scala Cats Lifting values into Monad Transformers

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am reading [this](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) documentation about lifting values into Monad Transformers.

Based on this I wrote the following code

```
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
type FutureOption[T] = OptionT[Future, T]
val x : FutureOption[Int] = 1.pure[FutureOption] // works
val y : FutureOption[Int] = OptionT.fromOption[Future](Some(10)) // works
val z : FutureOption[Int] = OptionT.liftF(Future.successful(10)) // works
```

Now if I try

```
val z = FutureOption[Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(Some(10)))
```

I get an error

```
cmd4.sc:1: no type parameters for method apply: (value: F[Option[A]])cats.data.OptionT[F,A] in object OptionT exist so that it can be applied to arguments (scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Int]])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Int]]
 required: ?F[Option[?A]]
val x : OptionT[Future, Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(Some(10)))
                               ^
cmd4.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Int]]
 required: F[Option[A]]
val x : OptionT[Future, Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(Some(10)))
                                                        ^
cmd4.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : cats.data.OptionT[F,A]
 required: cats.data.OptionT[scala.concurrent.Future,Int]
val x : OptionT[Future, Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(Some(10)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to Scala type inference.

In absence of an explicit `Option` type annotation, the type of `Some(10)` is `Some[Int]` which is a subtype of `Option[Int]`. However `OptionT` expects exactly `Option` so it won't compile.

You can make it compile by doing

```
val z: FutureOption[Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(Option(10)))
```

or

```
val z: FutureOption[Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(Some(10): Option[Int]))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the solution provided by Gabrielle. You can use the syntax provided by cats lib

```
import cats.syntax.option._
```

and then

```
val z: FutureOption[Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(10.some))

Or 

val z: FutureOption[Int] = OptionT(Future.successful(none[Int]))
```

`10.some` and `none[Int]` will be inferred to `Option[Int]`

P.S: there is also a syntax for Either through `cats.syntax.either._` `10.asRight[String]` and `"Oops".asLeft[Int]` will be inferred to `Either[String, Int]`